# are changes to a list inside a function preserved outside the function

Tags: python-3.x, list, function

We had the following example presented but it seems wrong.

```
What will be the output of the following Python code?

def a(b):
    b = b + [5]
 
c = [1, 2, 3, 4]
a(c)
print(len(c))
```

a) 4

b) 5

c) 1

d) An exception is thrown

Answer: a

Explanation: Since a list is mutable, any change made in the list in the function is reflected outside the function.

so b becomes [1,2,3,4,5].  so, is b a local variable or is b really c? if the latter then shouldn't the answer be 5?

when I try this the answer is 4 but then is the explanation just wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: The answer is (a), but the explanation makes no sense. There is no list mutation happening in this code. `b + [5]` is not a mutation; it is the creation of a new list. This list is assigned to a local name, and has no affect to the original list. They are two separate lists.

Comment: thanks, I think the word NOT needs to be added to the answer!

Comment: That wouldn't do it. It says *"any change made in the list in the function"*, but that is completely irrelevant, as no such change is made. It talks about things that aren't happening.

Comment: The function has `b = ...`, which _reassigns_ the name `b` to be a **brand new** local variable.  It is no longer connected to the variable `b` that was passed as an argument.

Comment: yep should be b += [5]

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all the function doesn't have any return statement. So even if a(c) is executed, it doesn't give any output.
2. Here a(c) is executed. but this function's output has no connection with the list c. They have only asked the length of the list c.

For example see the following code:

```
def a(b):
    b = b + [5]
    return b
 
c = [1, 2, 3, 4]
c = a(c)
print(len(c)) #output :5
```

In the above code, there is a return statement and the return value is declared as c. so the second list's element is added to the c and gives the length as 5.

Also it doesn't matter even if a list is outside a function. The function can change it's value. See the following example:

```
c = [1, 2, 3, 4]
def a(b):
    return c+b
d = a([5])
print(d) #output:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

There can be a question whether order in which declaring c matters. Yes, it matters, but c should be declared before calling the function. For eg., Even the following code will work.

```
def a(b):
    return c+b
c = [1, 2, 3, 4]
d = a([5])
print(d) #output : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

But when you declare c after calling the function it'll give error saying c is not defined

```
def a(b):
    return c+b
d = a([5])
c = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(d) # error : c is not defined
```

Here's the counter example to show that lists are indeed passed by reference - or at least the address is being passed by value:

```
def a(b): 
    b += [5] 
    print(len(b)) 

c = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
a(c) 
print(len(c))
```

in a(), when you have b = b + [5] you are creating a new address and in that case c will not be affected but, in the above case c is passed in, nothing is returned and c is updated outside of a()

Comment: even without the return statement c is updated

Comment: Show the example and then I'll explain

Comment: Take your first example. Just eliminate the return statement. Objects are passed by reference so c is still updated outside the function

Comment: No. You'll get error saying 'TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()'. 
 [Screenshot](https://imgur.com/nw8UeBZ)

Comment: I updated your answer.  see the example at the bottom

Comment: Yes, the difference here is b = b+[5] and b += [5]. Though these two considered as same, in the case of b += [5], here it has a hidden meaning that the value of b needs to be updated.

What I wanted to say is a function can change the value of variable outside it also, but should approach with common sense.

Comment: b = b + [5] is NOT the same as b+=[5]. In the first case we create a new memory address. In the second case we do not.